# Converting AddressOf from VB6 to c#

Tags: c#, vb6-migration, addressof

In VB6 we have the below code.

```
g_CTimer.TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, g_CTimer.Interval, AddressOf TimerProc)
```

The TimerProc method is as below

```
Sub TimerProc(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idEvent As Long, ByVal dwTime As Long)
    On Error Resume Next

    If g_CTimer Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    g_CTimer.ThatTime

End Sub
```

How do we convert that call "AddressOf TimerProc" in C#.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards
Achyuth

Comment: Just remove it. Method groups are implicitly converted to delegates. [`SetTimer(0, 0, g_CTimer.Interval, TimerProc)`]

Comment: Use the [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetTimer.html) web site to find proper declarations.  But just don't bother with this, the .NET Timer class already takes care of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can just omit the `AddressOf` keyword.  In VB.NET it explicitly implies that you are sending the method pointer as an argument (a pointer to `TimerProc`, in this case).  In C# you can just use the method name directly.

That said, you're probably better off just re-implementing this with a normal timer (`Windows.Forms.Timer` or some other).

Comment: @Achyuth you will still have four arguments - `AddressOf TimerProc` is one argument, you replace it with `TimerProc`.